# Orthonormal basis of the column space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Find an orthonormal basis of the column space of the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 & 2 & 3\\
-1 & 1 & -3 & 2\\
2 & -2 & 5 & -5 \end{pmatrix}.$$

I found the row reduced echelon form of the matrix given as $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$ So column space of the matrix is the span of $A$, where $A=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$.

How to proceed after this step?

Comment: Clearly $A$ is orthonormal, so Youŕe done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware that, in general, the pivot columns of the RREF are ***not*** a basis of the column space of the initial matrix.

A simple example is the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
(on the left the given matrix, on the right its RREF).

What you can say in general is that the columns of the initial matrix *corresponding* to the pivot columns in the RREF form a basis of the column space. In the particular case, it's irrelevant, but just because the matrix has rank $3$, so its column space is the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$ and any orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ will do. However, if you change the matrix into
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 2 & 3\\
-1 & 1 & -3 & -4\\
2 & -2 & 5 & 7
\end{pmatrix}
then the RREF is
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
so you get a basis of the column space as
$$
\mathcal{B}=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}2\\-3\\5\end{pmatrix}
\right\}
$$
You can obtain an orthonormal basis by applying, for instance, Gram-Schmidt to these two vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Since the second, the third and the fourth columns of the original matrix are linearly independent, the column space is $\Bbb R^3$ and therefore *any* orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^3$ (such as the standard basis) will do.